# How to check if a property of an Entity Framework type is Nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullable

I have a EntityDataModel generated from my database.
One of the Entity models has two properties that are both string types.
One is Nullable=True and the other Nullable=False

How do I check the value of the Nullable property during runtime ?

Comment: Perhaps not that elegant, but can't you simply set nullable to true in your EntityDataModel for buth entities? You can always check wether a Nullable holds a value using the `HasValue` property.

Comment: what is the issue? you can compare like `myEntity.Where( e=> e.NullableStringProperty =="ValueToCompare");`

Comment: @CommuSoft you cannot use `HasValue` on a string. This is only for value types. String is a reference type and it does not have this property.

Comment: I'm inspecting the model type for the "Nullable condition" not an instance

Answer (score 0):

If your properties are decorated with attributes like `[Required]` or `[StringLength]` with a property `MinimumLength` set to a value greater then 0, you could use that property's GetType() method. This method will return an object of type `Type` and it has a number of other methods like `GetCustomAttributes`. This method will return all the custom attributes applied to your property.

As I said earlier, if you know which attributes were applied, like the ones mentioned, then using `YourObject.YourProperty.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true)` will do the trick. You will need to go through the array and cast the result to the proper attribute.

Comment: I don't have an instance of the Model, just it's type. So I've tried ModelType.GetProperty("NameofTheProperty).PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(true), but none of the listed attributes are of type System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

Comment: I was giving you an example. Are you using Code-First, Model-First or Database-First approach? If you have a .edmx file then have a look at the generated code to see if there is any attribute applied.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I've got a edmx file from a Database-First approach. If I look at the partial classes for the modeled objects I don't see any attributes on the properties. For value type properties the type has been set to Nullable<> by the designer where Nullable=True in the edmx, but not for the string properties. Both a re just Public string Property1 {get;set;}. I had assumed that maybe the [Required] annotation was added at compile time ? Is the Nullable property in the edmx designer just a design time property maybe ?