# Get the 'Nullable' state programmatically of a Property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullable, propertyinfo

I need to get the Nullable property out for a field in EF. Some magic code needs to be done on properties that are Nullable=True, and I cannot find a working solution to get the property out.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in (PropertyInfo[])type.GetProperties())
{
   var getPropertyType = property.GetMethod.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes.ToString();

   var getValue = property.GetValue(model);
   bool isNullable = property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);

   // isNullable always returns false !!!! and I need it to return true if the field is allowed to be null

   if ((getValue == null) && (!isNullable))
   {
   }
}
```

Class

```
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace testApp.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the class that represents the `type` variable - it'll be useful to see which properties you expect to be nullable. At present the code looks sound (present suspicion is becuause GetProperties will only return all public properties by default, so I suspect your Nullable properties are non-public)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `Nullable=True` in Entity Framework doesn't give you a `System.Nullable<type>`.   Possible answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710697/how-to-check-if-a-property-of-an-entity-framework-type-is-nullable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710697/how-to-check-if-a-property-of-an-entity-framework-type-is-nullable)

Comment: @rich.okelly I can see the property in debug and get the value and data type of it, therefore, I believe that it isn't the problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m that is what i 'not want to do', as I have a humongous edmx and do not want to define each field as said in the post, and just want to get the nullable state as per the db structure

Comment: @DJJ,  can you post the class please?

Comment: @rich.okelly I've added the stub class as generated from the entity framework model. Remember, there are properties on the table in the model viewer where you can set the nullable state against each property, and this won't show in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the properties that are nullable in the database. That means that "some magic code" should look into the storage model of the EDMX. The class model doesn't contain this information, let alone the generated classes.

Here's how you can get a listing of all nullable properties in the storage model:

```
var tableName = "someTable";
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

var items = oc.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).OfType<EntityType>();
foreach (var entityType in items.Where(e => e.Name == tableName))
{
    var props = string.Join(",", entityType.Properties.Where(p => p.Nullable));
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", entityType.Name, props));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Where would I replace or specify the specific object that I'm looking at? I tried adding a lamda exp to the end of items based on the Name property but no luck. The solution would work in worst case scenario, but I have almost 700 tables to run through the for-each then to check for the specified table.

Comment: When looking into the storage model, `entityType.Name` is equal to a table name. Could you use that as input?

Comment: Yes you could but from an efficiency point of view, the loop will run almost 700 times for each entity object within the db, hence the question to filter the items set to the needed object.

Comment: Your the man!!!!! Thanks Mr. I've moved the lamba to the items line to get the table out, and then check on each respective property for the nullable state, thus removing the foreach loop completely.                  var items = oc.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).OfType<EntityType>().
                    Where(e => e.Name == "someTable").SingleOrDefault();
                var getProperty = items.Properties["someProperty"].Nullable;

Comment: DJJ I'm glad this worked out for you -- I'm still shaking my head that there isn't some kind of manifestation of this property in the generated code -- so one has to go to the storage model (or the database itself) to get this information.  And if you didn't, you get a runtime error.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx) Method for this

```
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) != null)
{
    // It's nullable
}
```

Comment: That makes essentially the same call as `GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)` and returns the underlying type, which will be whatever is inside the <> (eg Nullable<int> gives int)

Comment: yes, and thats what it says... if you get the underlying property for `Nullable` as `NOT NULL`, that means its `Nullable`.... If you dont get anything, its not `Nullable`...

Comment: I see now - thanks for clarifying.  `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` gives an error if it's not nullable, but this does not.

Comment: Tried and it's still returning false (meaning that it's not nullable) even though the property is set to null in the db.